# QuickLook plugins and Core Image filters

Tags: macos, core-image, quicklook

I'm writing a QuickLook plugin that uses a custom (system-wide installed) Core Image filter to combine two left/right views into an anaglyph. When launched through "qlmanage -p", everything works fine. But from the finder, the preview is blank... I attached to quicklookd and set some breakpoints to see what happens; there are no errors but the filter's output is a gray image. Mac OS X 10.6 with XCode 3.2.5. The plugin is marked as needing execution in the main thread.

Any hints ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

qlmanage process is a little different than the real process (quicklookd) that will execute your plugin. In short, qlmanage -p can connect to the window server while quicklookd forbids it, thus the different behaviors.

If you really want qlmanage to test your plugin in the same condition of quicklookd, try "qlmanage -p -z" instead of just "qlmanage -p". Only it won't display the result. You can then use gdb to debug your plugin.

Comment: Don't you mean `qlmanage -p -x`?  That makes it use quicklookd.

Comment: -p -z runs as -p except it's meant for performance timing so does not display the result so does not need a connection to the window server, so can run in the same condition as quicklookd. -x does send the request to quicklookd so you will reproduce your problem but not make it easy to debug.

Comment: Using -x does allow me to reproduce the problem but it's not easier to debug; since the plugin is called from quicklookd and not my code I still have to attach to the quicklookd process as I did before...

Comment: Though this is not actually an answer, I'll mark it as one cause it may be very usefull to other people. For the record, I used a different way to compute the anaglyph, without using a CoreImage filter and it works so CIFilter/quicklook don't seem to work well together.

Comment: More exactly GPU and Quick Look plugins don't work well together. This is a consequence of QL trying to sandbox plugins and protect the rest of the system from various problems while often handling non-trusted files.